# Takes forever :Project Euler Problem 3 Python

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I am a beginner. My Solution below for [Project Euler Problem No. 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) takes forever to return answer. Can anybody suggest improvement? what am i doing wrong? I have written pieces of codes to help me think of all the puzzle pieces of the problem.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

```
#limiter identification for iteration

def limiter(x):
    for i in range (2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return int (x/i)

#Prime checker 
            
def is_prime(a):
    for i in range (2, a):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
#Lists all factors of a given no.

def factorlist(b):
    list = []
    for i in range (2, limiter(b)+1):
        if b % i == 0:
            list.append(i)
    return list

#Lists all prime factors of a given no.

def primefactor(p):
    plist = []
    for i in factorlist(p):
        if is_prime(i)== True:
            plist.append(i)
            
    return plist
    
print (primefactor(600851475143)[-1])
```

Comment: For problems like this, it's always helpful to look at smaller cases that you know the answer to. Does this program actually return correct results for small numbers?

Comment: Yes, it does. If I just take out the last digit of the input it gives correct result fairly quickly. Adding the last digit seems to cause the delay.

Comment: 1) What's the idea behind `limiter`? 2) you only need to iterate until `sqrt(a)` when you check if it's prime (if one of the divisor is greater than `sqrt(a)`, the other is less). Not sure if that's the only issue, but certainly will make it faster.

Comment: Once you have something that basically works and you want to make it faster, try writing down the steps it follows for a small case. Are any of them repetitive? If so, is there a way you can avoid doing some of the repetition? For a typical early Euler problem (and really most problems in computer science), each step should get you a piece of your answer and leave you with a smaller version of the same problem, until the last step gives you the last piece.

Comment: I didn't think of sqrt(a). Thanks it should reduce calculation quite much. Tell me one more thingb; I appended all factors of the input in a list and then using iteration checked whether prime or not. If prime then appended to another list and eventually returning the last item. Is this approach memory efficient? Is there any other better approach. Recursion poses similar memory issue I believe.

Comment: It's up to you whether to use recursion in the ultimate solution, but thinking through the problem in a recursive way is really helpful for figuring out how to make the problem smaller bit by bit. The basic trick here is to find a factor, divide by it, and then work on the smaller problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the answer, but I will say that sometimes print() statements in the functions will prove to be useful to debug in functions. An example that your limiter() function hangs at 71. I found out running your program on my machine:

```
def limiter(x):
for i in range (2, x):
    print(i) <------------------ I added this
    if x % i == 0:
        return int (x/i)
```

So, adding print() in your functions may help.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach to find the largest prime factor is going to be simpler and probably much faster:

```
def lpf(N,p=2):                               # start from preceding prime factor
    for f in range(p,int(N**0.5)+1):          # factors up to square root
        if N%f==0 : return max(f,lpf(N//f,f)) # 1st prime vs lpf of counterpart
    return N # none found, N is prime itself

lpf(600851475143) # 6857
```

Answer (score 0):

here is lot simpler and shorter code:

```
# Largest Prime Factor

def prime_number(b):
    c1 = 0
    for i in range(1,int(b/2)+1):
        if b % i == 0:
            c1 += 1
    if c1 < 2:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def prime_factor(a):
    n = 0
    count = 1
    prime = 0
    while n < a+1:
        n += 1
        if a % n == 0:
            if prime_number(n) == True:
                prime = n
                print(prime)
prime_factor(600851475143)
```

Comment: for i in range(1,int(b/2)) sholud be  to for i in range(1,int(b/2)+1)